# masked own parameter in Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing

If i will make own link in symfony:

**http://www.mypage.com/phone/show/id/1**

for:

**http://www.mypage.com/linksone**

in routing:

```
linksone:
  url: /linksone
  param: { module: phone, action: show, id: 1 }
```

what if i use own parameter in URL?

how example:

**http://www.mypage.com/phone/show?number=3**

i dont have change this link for

**http://www.mypage.com/phone/show/number/3**

i must use:
**http://www.mypage.com/phone/show?number=3** - with /number/3 doesnt work.

is possible make routing with own parameter?

```
linksone:
  url: /linksone
  param: { module: phone, action: show, number: 3 }
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This page in the "Practical Symfony" tutorial explains the routing in Symfony: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05

You can introduce parameters in your URL like this:

```
linksone:
  url: /phone/show/:number
  param: { module: phone, action: show }
```

If you want to make the `:number` parameter optional, you can add the default value to the `param` option:

```
linksone:
  url: /phone/show/:number
  param: { module: phone, action: show, number: 1 }
```

Comment: thanks, but in this example i must use in url my parameter NUMBER. i would like add number automatically. I would like open http://www.mypage.com/newlink instead of http://www.mypage.com/phone/show?number=3. In your example i must open: http://www.mypage.com/newlink?number=3